# class package.X uses a non-entity package.Y as target entity in the relationship attribute field listOfQuestions

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to create web aplication which connects on derby database in eclipse. I added JPA facet in project facets. When I try to generate tables from entities, I get an error. Here is the first bit of stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicClassLoader@2a742aa2
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [lv10example] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.Answer] uses a non-entity [class ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.Question] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field listOfQuestions].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.buildEntityManagerFactory(Main.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:68)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [lv10example] failed.
```

Here is the code:

```
    @Entity
    public class Answer {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;
        private String text;
        private boolean correctStatus;
        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinTable(name="QuestionAnswer",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="answerID", 
   referencedColumnName="id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="questionID",
   referencedColumnName="id"))

    private Collection<Question> listOfQuestions;

    public Answer() {
        id=0;
        text="";
        correctStatus=false;
        listOfQuestions=null;
    }

    public Answer(int _id, String _text, boolean _correctStatus,Question question){
        id=_id;
        text=_text;
        correctStatus=_correctStatus;
        listOfQuestions.add(question);
    }
    ... Getters and setters ...

}
```

Here is the other class:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "TEST")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    private String text;
    private boolean answered;
    private int points;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listOfQuestions")
    private Collection<Quiz> listOfQuizzes;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listOfQuestions")
    private Collection<Answer> listOfAnswers;

    public Question() {
        id=0;
        text="";
        answered=false;
        points=0;
        listOfAnswers=null;
    }

    public Question(int _id,String _text, int _points,Answer answer){

        id=_id;
        text=_text;
        answered=false;
        points=_points;
        listOfAnswers.add(answer);
    }

    ... Getters and setters ...

}
```

Here is persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="lv10example">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> -->

        <class>ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.Quiz</class>
        <class>ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.Question</class>
        <class>ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.Answer</class>
        <class>ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.LoggedStatus</class>
        <class>ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.Result</class>
        <class>ba.fet.rwa.lv10.domain.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
            <!-- property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /-->         
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can someone help me with this? There is certainly an error in here somewhere, but i cannot find it. Maybe it's the problem with jpa facet? I tried to debug this for 2 days from now, but with no luck. Sorry for my bad English. Thank you! :-)

Comment: Are there any other method in the Question entity, which have some logic? i.e. equals / hashCode. If so, please add them to the question

Comment: For starters, you used the same field, `listOfQuestions ` in the `mappedBy` attribute of two different relationships. That's illegal in JPA

Comment: Ok, but I have another class named Quiz which has listOfQuestion field, (list of questions which belong to that quiz). I must map it somehow, I dont know...

Comment: @MaciejKowalski No I dont have any other methods beside getters and setters for now

Comment: @crizzis, the 2 `mapped-by` point to different classes ... `Quiz` and `Answer` hence not "illegal".

Comment: the file should be called `persistence.xml` not `persistance.xml`, but maybe you just posted that wrong?

Comment: It is called persistence.xml sorry :-) It is located in WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF